# Model.objects.create equivalent that performs a full_clean?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

So I've got the following code:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Text language.                                                                                 
    ENGLISH = 'eng'                                                                                   
    FRENCH  = 'fr'                                                                                   

    LANGUAGES_CHOICES = [                                                                            
        (ENGLISH, 'English'),                                                                        
        (FRENCH, 'French'),                                                                          
    ]                                                                                                

    language = models.CharField(                                                                     
            max_length=max(len(language) for language in LANGUAGES_CHOICES),                         
            choices=LANGUAGES_CHOICES,                                                               
            blank=False,                                                                             
            null=True)
```

When I do `MyModel(language='invalid').save()` or `MyModel.objects.create(language='invalid')`, the model is saved without complaint. Is there any convenience method that is equivalent to `Model.objects.create` that performs a `full_clean` before it saves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using model forms, the `full_clean` will be called as part of the form validation step.

In general, there isn't a convenience method that calls `full_clean`, but you could write your own.

Answer (score -1):

[Model.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/): This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do validation that requires access to more than a single field:

Comment: "...Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method."